# Mod_rewrite causing 404 error

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

These are the .htaccess files from two of my localhost sites.

Virtual host 1 (mysite1.com):

```
    # this is the initialization
Options         +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine 
RewriteRule ^news-07/?$ news_01_06_2007.php [NC,L] 
# Handle requests for "news"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ $1 [nc]
#RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ http://mysite1.com/$1 [R,NC]
```

However, when I try http://www.mysite1.com/testfile.php - it redirects to http://mysite.com/testfile as it should do, except this message is displayed:

> Not Found
>   The requested URL /testfile was not found on this server.

How can I resolve this error message and ensure my .htaccess file works?

I'm managing to understand .htaccess well, with regard to things like blocking spiders etc. but this one is causing me some problems, anyone know what's wrong and how I can prevent this error happening again in the future?

All help appreciated.

Comment: Well, it's doing exactly what you're telling it to do: It rewrites any `xyz.php` to `xyz`. Are you looking to do it the other way round maybe?

Comment: No, I was trying to write xyz.php to xyz - but it treated it as if there was no such file.

Not sure what I've done wrong...

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? By rewriting `xyz.php` to `xyz` apache will look for a file called `xyz` on your server. This likely doesn't exist. Are you trying to get pretty urls that load the associated PHP script?

Comment: Yes, I am trying to get 'pretty' URLs that load the associated script, that's correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be trying to do it backwards. Try something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  $1.php  [nc]
```

Answer (score 0):

Turn on `MultiViews` with

```
Options +MultiViews
```

This will work not only with .php files but with all files the client claims to accept in the request. See [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html). Note that wrong-but-working configurations in Apache have given a bad name to MultiViews in the past, see [here](http://www.devside.net/articles/php) to make sure you have Apache correctly configured.

If you want to use rewrite rules, I'd do this instead (untested):

```
RewriteCond $0 !\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.*$  $0.php [QSA]
```

The `QSA` flag is necessary in order for you not to lose the query string